# CSVTools Perl Script / EOF found whilst scanning for \CSVtolongtable third argument

Tags: tables, perl

Using the CSV Tools perl script (this is to remove the CSVTools commands so that everything is in one file), I'm getting the following error.  There is no EOF character in the CSV file (except at the end of the file).  Has someone else had this problem?  Here is the error:

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:Ellison-Glaeser tazz$ /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/doc/latex/csvtools/csvtools.pl EGstat.tex EGstatFlat.tex
Converting \CSVtotabular{paper_source_tables/HLeastTable.csv}
EOF found whilst scanning for \CSVtolongtable third argument on line 426
```

Here is the latex of the relevant lines:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Least Concentrated Industries in \citet{HolmesStevens2003}}\label{table:leastcon}
\centering
\scriptsize
\CSVtotabular{paper_source_tables/HLeastTable.csv}{rlrrrr}{
    \toprule
    97 NAICS &
    Name &
    Plant Herfindahl &
    Plants &
    $\gamma$ &
    95\% Sig\\\midrule
%\multicolumn{6}{c}{     $\gamma$ That Are Not Statistically Significant At 5\% Level Are Indicated by ``*"}\\\midrule
}{
    \insertbyname{NAICS}&
    \insertbyname{Name} &
    \insertbyname{Herfindahl} &
    \insertbyname{Plants} &
    \insertbyname{Gamma} &
    \insertbyname{Significants} 
    \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{csvrownumber} / 5) \relax = \value{csvrownumber}}{\\\seprule}{\\}
}{
    \insertbyname{NAICS}&
    \insertbyname{Name} &
    \insertbyname{Herfindahl} &
    \insertbyname{Plants} &
    \insertbyname{Gamma} &
    \insertbyname{Significants} 
    \\\bottomrule
}
```

Alternatively, it could be this (the long table after the above table):

```
\CSVtolongtable{paper_source_tables/SimulationResults.csv}{rccrrr}{
        \caption{Simulated Critical Values}\label{tab:simulationresults}\\\toprule
        Plants &
        $\sigma$ &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\underline{95\% Herfindahl Range}} &
        5\% $\gamma $  Critical Value &
         95\% $\gamma $  Critical Value\\\midrule
        \endfirsthead
        %\caption[]{Simulation Results}\\
        %\multirow{2}{*}{\small State}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{2001}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{1997}\\\cmidrule(l{3ex}r){2-3}\cmidrule(l{3ex}r){4-5}  EXAMPLE OF COMPLICATED UNDERLINING STRUCTURE
%&\multicolumn{1}{c}{VA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Percent}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{VA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Percent}\\\midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{l}{ \small \tablename\ \thetable{} -- \emph{continued from previous page}}\\
        \toprule
        Plants &
        $\sigma$ &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\underline{95\% Herfindahl Range}} &
        \bfseries 5\% $\gamma $ Critical Value &
        \bfseries 95\% $\gamma$ Critical Value\\\midrule
        \endhead
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{r}{ \em \small Continued on next page}
        \endfoot
        \\[-2ex]
        \multicolumn{6}{l}{ \small \textit{Source:} Author's calculations. }
        \endlastfoot
    }{
        \ifthenelse{\numexpr 12*( ( \value{csvrownumber} - 1 ) / 12) \relax = \numexpr ( \value{csvrownumber} -1 ) \relax }{\bfseries }{}\insertbyname{Plants} &
        \insertbyname{Standard Deviation} &
        \insertbyname{Low Herfindahl Range} &
        \insertbyname{High Herfindahl Range} &
        \insertbyname{Five Critical Value} &
        \insertbyname{Ninety Five Critical Value} 
        \ifthenelse{\numexpr 6*(\value{csvrownumber} / 6) \relax = \value{csvrownumber}}{\\\seprule}{\\}
    }{
        \insertbyname{Plants} &
        \insertbyname{Standard Deviation} &
        \insertbyname{Low Herfindahl Range} &
        \insertbyname{High Herfindahl Range} &
        \insertbyname{Five Critical Value} &
        \insertbyname{Ninety Five Critical Value} 
        \\\bottomrule
    }
```

However, none of this is anywhere near the line 426 and the CSV doesn't even have a line 426.

This produces a perfect PDF, it just doesn't seem to work with the perl script.